In Jack McDevitt’s book Time Travelers Never Die, how does Shel buy an apartment in the future?
Jack McDevitt’s novel Time Travelers Never Die (based on a novella of the same name, but this question is about the novel) features time travel into the past and the future. When the protagonists go to the past, they can easily obtain from antique shops and similar old money, fake documents, and other ‘local cover’ that let them blend in.
However, at one point in the book, one of the characters, Shell, purchases an apartment in the distant future (80 years ish). Given that an antique store can’t sell future documents or ID or give out future money, or fake documents that hold up 80 years on (like trying to use a licence made with 1944 tech today), how is this done?
I would love an explanation in the book if I missed it, but I’m also open to theories and extrapolation if not provided for in the text.

If I buy an apartment today, I'll still own it 80 years in the future. I don't need any fake documents to accomplish this, just money

To clarify, Shel travelled 80 years into the future to buy an apartment he did not own (and did not even exist, in a neigborbood that did not exist) in the present

Please let me know if my question was ambiguously worded on that point and I’ll edit for clarity

Specifically, Shel is in 2100, and the place is still under construction, so he hops ahead a few months and buys it when it's complete.  I just assumed that to get money he sold (offscreen as it were) some of the antiquities he'd collected, maybe something from Alexandria.  But I don't have a quote to back that up.

I've only glanced at the book, so I don't know if it's a good question or not. I do see that the characters discuss buying valuable artworks in the past, so funding and finance wouldn't be any sort of issue when it comes to buying property

@DavidW but even with antiquities he’d just have cash; how does he open a bank account, show ID, close put the deal, all of which require documentation? Unless I missed it, nothing in the text suggests that the 2100 world lets you buy an apartment with a wad of cash

And he can’t use his bank account from 2019, even assuming he could explain being a very young looking centenarian,  because that’s closed due to the key events in the novel…

Shel can't use "his" money because when he "died" he arranged for it all to go to charity, IIRC.  But he's smart and a time traveller; he can hop back from 2100 by approximately his apparent age, bribe a clerk with some Egyptian or Greek gold (or pawn the gold and use money) to create a birth record for him, hop a few years forward and arrange to create an account for that person, hop a few years later and deposit money to it as the "uncle," etc.

@DavidW - If I walked into a present day Estate Agent with a big pile of cash or gold and didn't really care how much of it they took, I dare say I could persuade the nice people there to sort me out with a house and make the paperwork requirements vanish into thin air

@Valorum this is certainly jurisdiction and agency specific, but in the book it’s a premium luxury development in a utopian future Philadelphia, and I have trouble seeing how the contracts, utilities, property taxes, anti money laundering etc, goes without docs in that case. A shell corporation might dodge things but opening a corporation also takes some level of bank capital and AML checks, not piles of gold.
